# How can I upload a model to the viewer by refering to a file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I initialize the viewer using this example https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/initialization/

But I do not load models immediately, only by an external event in the system (for example, pressing a button).

Question: how can I upload a model to the viewer by referring to a file (a local path or a path to my server) after initializing the viewer from the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you look at the [Simple Viewer](https://forge-tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/) tutorial. It guides you through the implementation of a simple Forge app where you can upload/translate/view designs during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the next chapter, you must upload your files using **DataManagement API** and then translate them using **ModelDerivative API** to load them in the viewer : [Load a model](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/load-a-model/)

If you want to load your models only after an external event, call the load function only when you want :

```
mybutton.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
})
```